# cant import matplotlib due to pycairo 1.20

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, setuptools

I have problems to import the matplotlibrary for my python3 script.

My system:
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
Python 3.6.8

Minimal reproduction:

Setup:

```
python3 -m venv tester
source tester/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib
pip list
```

Gives:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
certifi         2020.6.20
cycler          0.10.0
kiwisolver      1.2.0
matplotlib      3.3.2
numpy           1.19.2
Pillow          8.0.1
pip             18.1
pyparsing       2.4.7
python-dateutil 2.8.1
setuptools      40.6.2
six             1.15.0
```

Now to actual reproduction:

```
python3
>>>from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 15, in <module>
    import cairo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 21, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairocffi'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2336, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 277, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "/apps/shared/taifun/x86_64/apps/DATAPROCESSING/python/3.6.8/system/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/gpfs/apps/shared/mpo/tester/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 25, in <module>
    "is installed") from err
ImportError: cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
```

Ok, so we install pycairo:

```
pip install pycairo
```

Gives:

```
Collecting pycairo
  Downloading <internal-package-server>/5a10cb7f9ae0d/pycairo-1.20.0.tar.gz (344kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 3.7MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
Installing collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo ... done
Successfully installed pycairo-1.20.0
```

Lets check:

```
pip list
```

Seems ok:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
...
pycairo         1.20.0
...
```

New try:

```
python3
>>>from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Nope, same error:

```
...
ImportError: cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
```

Now, adapting the version to 1.11 works:

```
pip uninstall pycairo
pip install pycairo==1.11
python3
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>>
```

Hurray!

But why is pycairo 1.20 not working here? 1.11 -> 1.20 shouldn't be a breaking change and someone else should have notized this issue earlier. What might I be missing? Or should I actually open a ticket at matplotlib so they adapt their req. list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you install the latest version of cairocffi "pip install cairocffi"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve the issue. Several steps were necessary:

- Switch from pycairo to cairocffi (as CForce99 suggested)
- Update pip and setuptools (via entry to the gitlab-cy.yml), old version (40.x) had problems with cairocff's .tar.gz
- Set the path to the certificate for my corporate's internal pypi mirror (export REQUEST_CA_BUNDLE)